# jQuery, remove all instances with class from cloned element

Tags: jquery

Trying to remove with jQuery all selectors with a specific class from a cloned element with children.
Original markup:

```
<div id="el">
  <div class="remove">remove from clone</div>
  <div class="remain">remain in clone</div>
  <div class="remove">remove from clone</div>
  <div class="remain">remain in clone</div>
  <div class="remove">remove from clone</div>
  <div class="remain">remain in clone</div>
</div>
```

Cloned version should look like this:

```
<div id="el">
  <div class="remain">remain in clone</div>
  <div class="remain">remain in clone</div>
  <div class="remain">remain in clone</div>
</div>
```

jQuery code (not working for my purpose):

```
var clone = $('#el').clone();
clone = $(clone).remove('.remove');
clone = clone.html();
console.log(clone);
```

When I log to see if the remove elements exists in the clone, it puts out the correct number:

```
console.log($(clone).find('.remove').length);
```

Anyone can help on this.
Thanks so much! (possible duplicate though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage of `remove()` isn't quite right as the selector you provide is used to *filter* the current set of elements, not *find* within them.

To achieve what you require you need to use `find()` then `remove()` separately, like this:

```js
var $clone = $('#el').clone();
$clone.find('.remove').remove();
var clone = $clone.html();
console.log(clone);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="el">
  <div class="remove">remove from clone</div>
  <div class="remain">remain in clone</div>
  <div class="remove">remove from clone</div>
  <div class="remain">remain in clone</div>
  <div class="remove">remove from clone</div>
  <div class="remain">remain in clone</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `$(clone).remove('.remove');`

This is suggesting remove the cloned element if it has the class `remove`

You need to use `find()` since that class is nested inside the element

```
var clone = $('#el').clone();
clone.find('.remove').remove();
clone = clone.html();
console.log(clone);
```

Comment: This is suggesting remove the cloned element if it has the class remove -> thanks for explaining and pointing this out!